# Create PDF File with DriveApp.createFile with results of UrlFetchApp.fetch

Tags: pdf, google-apps-script

I cannot create a PDF file in my Google Drive from content retrieved using UrlFetchApp.fetch

If I email the same file attached It arrives properly.
Here is my code:

```
var codigo ="1100016795766";
var url = "http://do.convertapi.com/Web2Pdf";
var headers = {"Content-Type":"multipart/form-data"
        };

var payload=  {"ApiKey":"xxxxxxxx",
             "CUrl":"http://www.correos.cl/SitePages/seguimiento/seguimiento.aspx?envio="+codigo,
             "LowQuality":true
            }
var options = { "method":"POST",
  "headers": headers,
  "payload":payload,
  "muteHttpExceptions":false
  };
var       pdf0=UrlFetchApp.fetch(url,options);

//trying several ways
var        pdf=pdf0.getContent();
var       pdf1=pdf0.getAs('application/pdf');
var       pdf2=pdf0.getAs("application/pdf");
var       pdf3=pdf0.getContentText();


//Trying several ways, none of them get a valid PDF file

DriveApp.createFile("8track_correos.pdf", pdf, 'application/pdf');
DriveApp.createFile("9track_correos.pdf", pdf0,'application/pdf');
DriveApp.createFile("1track_correos.pdf", pdf1, MimeType.PDF);
DriveApp.createFile("2track_correos.pdf", pdf1, MimeType.PDF);
DriveApp.createFile("4track_correos.pdf", pdf3);
DriveApp.createFile("7track_correos.pdf", pdf2);
DriveApp.createFile("6track_correos.pdf", pdf1);


//The attached file arrives as a good PDF file

MailApp.sendEmail("user@gmail.com", "prueba de enviar PDF", "k", {attachments:[{fileName:prefijo+p_nombre+p_apellido+"track_correos.pdf", content:pdf, mimeType:"application//pdf"}]});
```

Comment: You don't show what the connections are between the sections of code.  So, the `UrlFetchApp.fetch()` is to get a file that is *not* on a Google Drive?

Comment: I added the inital part (connections)..
The email with attached pfd arrives OK, to gmail, it can be previewed properly.
But every pdf created directly in gdrieve is corrupted.

Comment: `UrlFetchApp.fetch()` returns an HTTPResponse Class.  From there, you can use `getAs('application/pdf')`, which you've done.  So, up until that point, I don't see any problem.  Then you are using `DriveApp` to create a file.  Why are you creating the file?

Comment: I want to save to Gdrive what I have gotten using getAs('application/pdf'), so I think I have to create a file with the content gotten. Is that correct?
How can I get the pdf saved in my Gdrive?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only `createFile()` configuration that allows a blob as the file source is:

DriveApp.createFile(blob);

So, you need to use:

```
var pdf0 = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url,options);
var pdf1 = pdf0.getAs('application/pdf');
var myNewFile = DriveApp.createFile(pdf1);
myNewFile.setName("track_correos.pdf");
```

Comment: Excellent It worked! I have my pdf saved in my Gdrive!!!

(I dont have enough points for vote up your answer!!!)Thank you very much!!